# Inserting two values from one variable into database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, innodb

I've got two different tables 'user' and 'candidates' and I'm trying to add values from one table to another by user selection.

This is the code displaying 'name' and 'surname' rows from 'user' table:

```
    echo "<select class='form-control custom-select' name='candid'>";
     while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
     {
      $candid = $row['name'] .' '. $row['surname'];
      echo "<option value='.$candid.'>".$candid."</option>";
     }
     echo "</select>";
```

I concatenated two columns and assigned their values to $candid variable.
Now I need to add these values to the 'name' and 'surname' columns in 'candidates' table. I also tried other version of this code:

```
     while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
     {
      echo "<option value='candid'>".$row['name'] .' '. $row['surname']."</option>";
     }
```

With this SQL query:

```
    $sql = ("INSERT INTO candidates (name, surname) VALUES ('$row[name]', '$row[surname]')");
      
    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE)
    {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    }
    else
    {
        // $conn->error only for testing purposes
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
```

But it doesn't work, so there is my question. Is it possible to do this using only PHP and SQL?

Comment: It is a very bad idea to use `$conn->error` in your code, because it could potentially leak sensitive information. See this post for more explanation: [mysqli or die, does it have to die?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15320411/1839439)

Comment: If you're trying to use user input, you should be using `$_POST` variables. `$row` was used when you were creating the HTML, it's not available when the user submits the form.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, I know that, it works fine with <input> tag but I need to use it somehow with <select> and I don't know how.

Comment: Why do you think it's any different with `<select>`? It's still in `$_POST['candid']`.

Answer (score 1):

When the user submits the form, the selected value is in `$_POST['candid']`. You can split that at the space and then insert into the table.

```
list($name, $surname) = explode(' ', $_POST['candid'], 2);
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO candidates (name, surname) VALUES(?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $name, $surname);
if ($stmt->execute()) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Record not created";
    error_log("candidate record not created: $conn->error");
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution with various changes in my code but it doesn't seem to work. All I get is this error message:
Notice: Undefined index: candid in D:\xampp\htdocs\adminlte\scripts\add_candidate.php on line 19
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in D:\xampp\htdocs\adminlte\scripts\add_candidate.php on line 19


Line 19 in my code:
list($name, $surname) = explode(' ', $_POST['candid'], 2);

Comment: This code should only run when you submit the form. It should be inside something like `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` -- replace `submit` with the name of the form's submit button. This is standard PHP form processing, you should read a tutorial.